# Custom template file for taxonomy term in drupal 7

Tags: taxonomy-terms, theming, upgrading

I need to create only one `tpl.php` file for all taxonomy terms in my website. I know `taxonomy_term_page.tpl.php` will do the required function in Drupal6.

For drupal 7 I had override the `taxonomy-term.tpl.php`. I see all the nodes associated to a term, is displayed at the last.

How can I hide those nodes?

Answer (score 3):

taxonomy-term.tpl.php is used in Drupal 7. You can find it in ROOT_DIRECTORY\modules\taxonomy\taxonomy-term.tpl.php.
To override this template, copy it, place it in your theme template directory, and modify it. Don't forget to clear the cache to see the output from the modified template.

Do not modify any core files (including template files), in any case.

If you want to show only the details of taxonomy term then you can create a view of type 'Term referance' with suitable filter.

Comment: Please add more information regarding how to override tpl.. Otherwise OP will end up editing core file :-) It's very important to explain your answers in a Drupal way...

Comment: To override tpl you can find detail information here https://drupal.org/node/1089656

Comment: I'm Still facing some problems. As i had override the taxonomy-term.tpl.php, i see all the nodes associated to a term, is displayed at the last. How can i hide those nodes?? Thanks in Advance... :)

Comment: @user26647 Don't ask question in comment for solution. Edit the question, Ask what you want and what problem you facing to achive them

Comment: Hi @Rupesh Thanks for ur response. I had modified my question. Please help me to find a solution. Thanks

Comment: @Paulraj Go through the modifid answer.

Answer (score -1):

To override tpl you can find detailed information in "[Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089656)".

Comment: Please enhance your answer to provide more details abut the "detailed information" that you think is relevant to answer this question ...